# How do I use the preamble.js file in emscripten?

Tags: javascript, emscripten, webassembly

I'm trying to get started with a small web-application with webassembly, and I'm using emscripten. Emscripten has this ["preamble.js" file](https://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/api_reference/preamble.js.html) that "*provide programmatic access for interacting with the compiled C code*". My problem is that I don't understand how to actually use this file. It's not javascript code so my browser can't load it, and it's not C/C++ code so my compiler can't compile it. So what do I do with it?

Sorry if this is painfully obvious or  documented somehwere, but I can't see it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`preamble.js` by itself can't be loaded in a browser, but when you use emscripten to generate a JavaScript (or HTML) output file (e.g. by invoking `emcc foo.c -o foo.js`), it will include a preprocessed version of the preamble along with your asm.js code in the output file. (Or if you use WebAssembly, it will also generate a `foo.wasm` file to go along with `foo.js`). The output `foo.js` file should be loadable in the browser (or e.g. node.js if it doesn't use web APIs).

Comment: Thanks! The emscripten developer added some information to clarify this for new users: https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/issues/4964